# Match first fields of two tab separated files and print matching values

Tags: awk

I have two files.

Match the `1st` column of first file to `1st` column of second file and print entire line of the second file.

Second file is a `<tab>` separated file.

I have tried many `awk` one liners, but all remove duplicate values. Like `A` and `C` here. I want to preserve these.

`File 1`:

```
A
B
C
D
A
C
```

`File 2`:

```
A abc
B cde
C abe
D acc
```

Output:

```
A abc
B cde
C abe
D acc    
A abc
C abe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next};{print a[$1]}' file2 file1
A abc
B cde
C abe
D acc
A abc
C abe
```