# Grep for searching pattern in a file

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to use `grep` to search pattern from one file in a second one.
My pattern file is something like:

```
K02217
K07448
KO8980
```

The file to search in is:

```
>aai:AARI_24510  proP; proline/betaine transporter; K03762 MFS transporter, MHS family, proline/betaine transporter
>aai:AARI_26600  ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
>aai:AARI_28260  hypothetical protein
>aai:AARI_29060  ABC drug resistance transporter, inner membrane subunit; K09686 antibiotic transport system permease protein
>aai:AARI_29070  ABC drug resistance transporter, ATP-binding subunit (EC:3.6.3.-); K09687 antibiotic transport system ATP-binding protein
>aai:AARI_29650  hypothetical protein
>aai:AARI_32480  iron-siderophore ABC transporter ATP-binding subunit (EC:3.6.3.-); K02013 iron complex transport system ATP-binding protein [EC:3.6.3.34]
>aai:AARI_33320  mrr; restriction system protein Mrr; K07448 restriction system protein
```

The command I tried is:

```
fgrep --file=pattern.txt file.txt >> output.txt
```

This prints the lines of file.txt where the pattern is found. I need it to print also a column with the pattern found. So something like:

```
K07448 mrr; restriction system protein Mrr; K07448 restriction system
K02217 ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
```

Anyone can suggest me how to do?

Comment: Actually my case is a bit different, because the patterns in the file pattern.txt are repeated more times in file.txt. I want it to search recursively and pronti g all the lines where the pattern is found...

Comment: Then I can't search for the pattern in a specific column, because the position in file.txt is random...

Comment: Can a single line match more than one pattern?

Comment: No, each line of file.txt match only one of pattern.txt

Comment: I just closed and re-opened since it already had three wrong votes to close as a duplicate. It is not. At least not of [the proposed one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140275/match-first-fields-of-two-tab-separated-files-and-print-matching-values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shell loop:

```
$ while read pat; do 
    grep "$pat" file | 
        while read match do 
            echo -e "$pat\t$match"
        done
 done < patterns 
KO3435  Xxxxx KO3435;folding factor
KO3435  Yyyyy KO3435,xxxx
KO3322  proteinaseK (KO3322)
```

I tested by running this on the UniProt flat file for human (625M) and using 1000 UniProt IDs as the patterns. It took ~6 minutes on my Pentium i7 laptop. It took ~35 seconds when I only looked for 100 patterns.

---

As pointed out in the comments below, you can make this slightly faster by skipping the `echo` and using `grep`'s `--label` and `-H` options:

```
$ while read pat; do 
    grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H < file
done < patterns
```

---

Running this on your example files produces:

```
$ while read pat; do 
    grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H < kegg.annotations; 
  done < allKO.IDs.txt > test1
terdon@oregano foo $ cat test1 
K02217:>aai:AARI_26600  ferritin-like protein; K02217 ferritin [EC:1.16.3.1]
K07448:>aai:AARI_33320  mrr; restriction system protein Mrr; K07448 restriction system protein
```

Comment: Possible problem with this is that you get duplicate lines if they contain two different patterns. Or this is possibly an improvement; I can not know what OP wants.

Comment: @CameronNemo good point, which is why [I asked the OP](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168342/grep-for-searching-pattern-in-a-file/168347?noredirect=1#comment277129_168342) [who said that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168342/grep-for-searching-pattern-in-a-file/168347?noredirect=1#comment277130_168342) each line can only match one pattern.

Comment: @terdon - I wonder if this would be any faster (using `--label`): `while read pat; do < file grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H; done < patterns` (output is a bit different but still along the same lines).

Comment: @don_crissti looks like that cuts about 1 second from my test with 100 patterns. Nice! I'd never noticed the `--label` option before. Shamelessly stolen and added to my answer.

Comment: I tried terdon solution as follows: while read allKO.IDs.txt; do  grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H < kegg.annotations; done > test1 but I had this error allKO.IDs.txt': not a valid identifier Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis what don said. The construct `while read var; do ... done < file` will read each line of `file` and save that line as `$var`.

Comment: I tried, but the file created was empty... but if I manually grep some of the patterns, it finds them...

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis I used the files from your example, ran `while read pat; do grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H < kegg.annotations; done < allKO.IDs.txt > test1` and got the expected result. If you ran _exactly_ that and it failed, please [edit] your question showing the command you ran and @ ping me again.

Comment: Hi terdon, I edited the question modifying the example files. I'm sorry, I didn't think it could make a difference

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis it still works fine here. See updated answer. Is that the exact command you ran?

Comment: this is exacly what I ran: while read pat; do grep "$pat" --label="$pat" -H < /home/angela/Programmes/mblastXNew/mblastx/Francesca/kegg1/kegg.annotations; done < /home/francescaDF/Programmes/allKO.IDs.txt >> test4 but the file is still empty

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis if that failed, there are no hits. There is probably something strange with your files. Was the `allKO.IDs.txt` file created on Windows perhaps? Windows line endings are different and that would mean that the pattern read is actually `K02217\r` instead of `K02217`. You can check by running `head -1 allKO.IDs.txt | od -c`, look for any strange characters that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hi terdon, yes you were right, my file has some thing strange: 0000000   K   0   0   8   4   4  \r  \n
0000010
I copied this column from an excel sheet in word pad. Is there any way to fix it up?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis ah! Thought so. OK, run `tr -d '\r' < allKO.IDs.txt > newfile` and then use `newfile` to search for your matches.

Comment: Hi terdon, thanks that worked! would it still work if I have a pattern file with 2 or more columns?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis no, each line is treated as a single pattern so `foo    bar` will _only match `foo   bar` and not `foo something else bar`. There are various ways to deal with that but please post a new question, providing both input and desired output files. Also, please remember to accept one of the answers here if they solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind an extra column with a number in it you can use `join` and `grep` to do this.

```
$ join <(grep -of patterns.txt file.txt | nl) \
       <(grep -f patterns.txt file.txt | nl)
1 KO3322 proteinaseK (KO3322)
2 KO3435 Xxxxx KO3435;folding factor
3 KO3435 Yyyyy KO3435,xxxx
```

Comment: Nice. And of course we can strip off that first field using awk or sed, if desired.

Comment: @PM2Ring - correct, didn't want to muddle up the A any more. OP or whomever can take this from here and use as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/):

```
$ ack "$(tr '\n' '|' < pattern.txt | sed -e 's/.$//')" --print0 --output='$& $_' file.txt
KO3322 proteinaseK (KO3322)
KO3435 Xxxxx KO3435;folding factor
KO3435 Yyyyy KO3435,xxxx
```